# XSLT mapping to remove namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

1. I am quite new to XSLT mapping and am stuck. I din understand the use of some functions.
   Please suggest some tutorials to read through.
2. I have input code below:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <ns0:hr xmlns:ns0="Namesapace.com">
   <Resources>
       <EmployeesRecords>
               <Record RecordId="1">
                       <Name>AAA € </Name>
                       <ID>111</ID>
                       <Phone>1111111111</Phone>
               </Record>
               <Record RecordId="2">
                       <Name>BBB</Name>
                       <ID>222</ID>
                       <Phone>2222222222</Phone>
               </Record>
       </EmployeesRecords>
       <ContractorsRecords>
               <Record RecordId="3">
                       <Name>ZZZ</Name>
                       <ID>999</ID>
                       <Phone>9999999999</Phone>
               </Record>
       </ContractorsRecords>
   </Resources>
   </ns0:hr>
   ```

and am expecting something like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Resources>
<EmployeesRecords>
    <Record RecordId="1">
        <Name>AAA € </Name>
        <ID>111</ID>
        <Phone>1111111111</Phone>
    </Record>
    <Record RecordId="2">
        <Name>BBB</Name>
        <ID>222</ID>
        <Phone>2222222222</Phone>
    </Record>
</EmployeesRecords>
<ContractorsRecords>
    <Record RecordId="3">
        <Name>ZZZ</Name>
        <ID>999</ID>
        <Phone>9999999999</Phone>
    </Record>
</ContractorsRecords>
</Resources>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Input code <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns0:hr xmlns:ns0="Namesapace.com">
 <Resources>
  <EmployeesRecords>
   <Record RecordId="1">
    <Name>AAA € </Name>
    <ID>111</ID>
    <Phone>1111111111</Phone>
   </Record>
   <Record RecordId="2">
    <Name>BBB</Name>
    <ID>222</ID>
    <Phone>2222222222</Phone>
   </Record>
  </EmployeesRecords>
  <ContractorsRecords>
   <Record RecordId="3">
    <Name>ZZZ</Name>
    <ID>999</ID>
    <Phone>9999999999</Phone>
   </Record>
  </ContractorsRecords>
 </Resources>
</ns0:hr>

Comment: can you provide your xslt code?

Comment: Is your requirement to copy all the elements in the output XML except `<ns0:hr>`? If that's the case, try to read on `Identity Transformation` and that should help you create the XSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its unclear from your question exactly what you are trying to do, but given the question title, the following XSLT should remove all the namespaces....

But be aware, the namespaces are part of the XML element/attribute names, so removing them fundamentally changes the XML document.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2017 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <!-- Stylesheet to remove all namespaces from a document -->
    <!-- NOTE: this will lead to attribute name clash, if an element contains
        two attributes with same local name but different namespace prefix -->
    <!-- Nodes that cannot have a namespace are copied as such -->

    <!-- template to copy elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to copy attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from seeing your input and output what the actual transformation rules are. For example, how do you decide that the first record should have

```
<Name>AAA € </Name>
<ID>111</ID>
```

rather than

```
<Name>AAA</Name>
<ID>€ 111</ID>
```

Once you have decided the rules, implementing them in XSLT 2.0 using the xsl:analyze-string instruction should be straightforward. In XSLT 1.0 (which many people are still using despite being 18 years old) it's likely to be rather more difficult.

As for your request for tutorials, I can only recommend my book: XPath 2.0 and XSLT 2.0 Programmer's Reference, 4th Edition, from Wiley/Wrox.